# Extract only matching pattern in a single line of text

Tags: sed

I have a compressed Javascript file which is in a single line form and contains

```
bla bla bla,;xyz=require("something"),blablabla=3xyz; if (require("somethingElse") === bla bla
```

I want to extract the required `something` and `somethingElse` from this "string". Here is the code I could build so far:

```
$ echo $script | sed 's|require(\([^)]*\))|\nget-this \1\n|g' | grep get-this | sed 's|get-this ||'
```

Output is:

```
something
somethingElse
```

How can I make this in a proper way?

## Edit

Exact working code is follows:

```
cat app.min.js | grep -o 'require("[a-ZA-Z0-9]\+")' | grep -o '".*"' | sed 's/"//g'
```

Produces:

```
Wifi
net
FlashEEPROM
abc1234
DS18B20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` has a `-o` or `--only-matching` option you can use for this, from `man grep`

> ```
>    -o, --only-matching
>           Print only the matched (non-empty) parts  of  a  matching  line,
>           with each such part on a separate output line.
> ```

So for me this:

```
$ cat compressed_js_file  | grep -o 'require("[[:alpha:]]\+")'
```

produces

```
require("something")
require("somethingElse")
```

Comment: Shorter: `grep -o 'require("[[:alpha:]]\+")' compressed_js_file`.

Answer (score 1):

A longer way using only `awk`:

```
awk -F "require" '{print $2 $3}' compressed_js_file | awk -F '[()"]' '{print $3"\n"$8}'
```

It produces:

```
something
somethingelse
```